# SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<', what does that mean?

Tags: javascript, html, button, external

I know this is asked a few times on S.O.

but none of the answers seem to match my situation . So, I have a a basic Html page which tries to use an external JS. The JS file tries to change the content of a paragraph defined in the HTML on a button click, but does not seem to work.

I see the following errors in console :

1)SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

2)ReferenceError: change is not defined

JSFiddle showing exact source?(except that  &  tags are removed as jsfiddle  - http://jsfiddle.net/p9ko4yde/

HTML Code :

```
<h1> Numbers with external script:) </h1>
<p id="number">1</p>
<button type="button" onclick="change()">Toggle between 1 and 2</button>

<script src="myScript.js"></script>



</body>
</html>
```

JS Code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function change(){
        var number = document.getElementById('number').innerHTML;
        if(number == '1'){
            document.getElementById('number').innerHTML='2';
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('number').innerHTML='1';
        }
    }
</script>
```

File Structure is as below:[image]

Comment: this can also happen when a server side script errors and dumps out some HTML, but does so in an embedded context

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't need the `<script>` tags when in an external .js file. Use these tags to embed a script inside HTML only.

Comment: Furthermore, any HTML tags inside .js file are illegal.

Answer (score 4):

The syntax error is because you have `<script>` tags in your JS file. When you put JavaScript in its own file like that, you don't need to surround it with script tags; that's HTML, and this is a JavaScript file.

The reference error is happening because, due to the syntax error, the JS file isn't executing correctly and so the change function never got created -- fixing the syntax error should also resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

In a js file, you do not use the HTML to declare that it is a js file.  So, you can drop the script tag in myScript and change it to this :

```
function change(){
    var number = document.getElementById('number').innerHTML;
    if(number == '1'){
        document.getElementById('number').innerHTML='2';
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('number').innerHTML='1';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes this error happens when the Javascript referenced **file doesn't exist**. Make sure that the file name is correct and you have the file in place. I know your problem is solved but maybe this answer solves someone else's :)