# Jquery Hide Show Not Working

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to work on my Jquery to hide and show text, and it's not working.  And I'm POSITIVE it's something stupid.

Here's my **HTML**:

```
<script src="js/showhide.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        <button class="btn btntruespeed" id="showdsl6">DSL 6</button>
        <p>DSL 6 is perfect for anyone who is a light Internet user.  It's perfect for those who only have 1-2 devices in the house, and they go on Facebook, and check and send emails.</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And **showhide.js** file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").hide();
  $('#showdsl6').click(function(){
    $("p").show();
  });
});
```

I'm not sure what's wrong, can someone help please?  Thanks.

Comment: It's working like a charm! [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c5jb7k7m/) do you want to toggle? or you mean not working at all?

Comment: Hi I don't know exactly what contains your file showhide.js, but if you use jquery inside, it better to include jquery.min.js before include showhide.js. i hope this help you

Comment: @pedram No, that jsFiddle worked perfectly.  I don't know where the disconnect is.

Comment: @Fender on my live code, I switched places with my showhide.js and jquery.min.js

Comment: Ok @ThomasHutton and it works fine or not ?

Comment: @Fender Unfortunately not yet.  In my Firebug console it's giving me: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

On my JS file, and Jquery.

Comment: someone had also this problem see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894074/syntaxerror-expected-expression-got) it is the same error you have @ThomasHutton

Comment: another solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31926326/syntaxerror-expected-expression-got-what-does-that-mean)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the order you are including the js files is wrong.
Try this:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/showhide.js"></script>
```

Comment: @ThomasHutton If you call for `$()` object before loading jquery.min.js, it will not be declared yet

Comment: Thanks, but the issue in my console is: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should swap the order in which you're including your scripts in the page. You're including your script first and jQuery afterwards. But your script depends on jQuery, so it should be included afterwards. Besides just giving it a try you could also confirm this by checking your console for a `$ is undefined error`.

Comment: I wonder why these downvotes when your answer is actually correct

Comment: It may not solve all the problems you're having but it's a necessary part of the solution. Are you still getting an error? Can you paste the full error message here?

Comment: @user6136528 This is in my console view: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'.

Comment: Is that your entire html and your entire JS file? If not, please post them in full if possible. There seems to be something missing. Nothing in that code seems to generate that error you're getting

Answer (score 0):

since toggle has been depreciated i have done it in other way.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").hide();
  $('#showdsl6').click(function(){
   if ($("p").css("display") == "none") {
       $("p").show();
    } else {
       $("p").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/showhide.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        <button class="btn btntruespeed" id="showdsl6">DSL 6</button>
        <p>DSL 6 is perfect for anyone who is a light Internet user.  It's perfect for those who only have 1-2 devices in the house, and they go on Facebook, and check and send emails.</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").hide();
  $('#showdsl6').click(function(){
    $(this).next().find('p').show();
  });
});
```