# JavascriptError: SyntaxError: expected expression, got ':' when use driver.executeScript(':screenshot') Selenium

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I try to send a command to the console and get a screenshot of one of the DOM tags but when I try to send it I get this error

```
\`\~\\Desktop\\selenium\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\error.js:522
let err = new ctor(data.message)
^

JavascriptError: SyntaxError: expected expression, got ':'
at Object.throwDecodedError (\~\\Desktop\\selenium\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\error.js:522:15)
at parseHttpResponse (\~\\Desktop\\selenium\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\http.js:548:13)
at Executor.execute (\~\\Desktop\\selenium\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\http.js:474:28)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async Driver.execute (\~\\Desktop\\selenium\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\webdriver.js:735:17) {
remoteStacktrace: ''
}\`
```

I need to get a screenshot node with selenium js firefox, it's the only way I could find and the most promising

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31926326/syntaxerror-expected-expression-got-what-does-that-mean

Comment: could you please post your code?

Comment: Possibly an old browser that doesn't support `let`?